# How can i detect operation system with asp.net

Tags: c#, iphone, asp.net, ipad, operating-system

i have a web site and i was used flash application.This flash applications not appear on IPad and IPhone.if operation system Ipad or Iphone i want to shown javascript application.i'm using below code but this code getting only platform information such as Win32NT.

```
OperatingSystem os = Environment.OSVersion;
os.Platform.ToString();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use  [Request.UserAgent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.useragent.aspx). That will give you what you need. Please not that UserAgent may return a wrong information as browser can allow you to change this. 

 [Also check out this article Detecting a mobile browser in ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34422/Detecting-a-mobile-browser-in-ASP-NET)

```
 if (Request.UserAgent.IndexOf("Windows NT 5.1") > 0)
        {
//xp
        }
        else if (Request.UserAgent.IndexOf("Windows NT 6.0") > 0)
        {
//VISTA
        }
        else if (Request.UserAgent.IndexOf("Windows NT 6.1") > 0)
        {
//7
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private string getOS()
{
    string os = null;
    if (Request.UserAgent.IndexOf("Windows NT 5.1") > 0)
    {
        os ="Windows XP";
        return os;
    }
    else if (Request.UserAgent.IndexOf("Windows NT 6.0") > 0)
    {
        os= "Windows Vista";
        return os;
    }
    else if (Request.UserAgent.IndexOf("Windows NT 6.1") > 0)
    {
        os = "Windows 7";
        return os;
    }
    else if (Request.UserAgent.IndexOf("Intel Mac OS X") > 0)
    {
        //os = "Mac OS or older version of Windows";
        os = "Intel Mac OS X";
        return os;
    }
    else
    {
        os = "You are using older version of Windows or Mac OS";
        return os;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to check Request.UserAgent for OS information, see this article: http://dnohr.dk/aspnet/how-to-detect-browser-operating-system-os-with-aspnet

```
OperatingSystem os = Environment.OSVersion;
os.Platform
```

returns the operating system of the server hosting your asp.net site...